# Const overloading and polymorphysm

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading, return-by-reference

I have an accessor member function (e.g. `operator[]`) that is const-overloaded:

```c
class Container {

public:
    Foo&       operator[](int i);
    const Foo& operator[](int i) const{
        return const_cast<Container *>(this)->operator[](i);
    }
};
```

Here, `const Foo& operator[] const` is defined in this way so that the same thing is not defined twice.

Now I want to make `Container` a base class, and `operator[]` becomes virtual:

```c
class BaseContainer {

public:
    virtual Foo& operator[](int i) = 0;
    const Foo& operator[](int i) const{
        // Is this correct?
        return const_cast<BaseContainer *>(this)->operator[](i);
    }
};

class DerivedContainer : public BaseContainer {
public:
    Foo& operator[](int i);
};
```

Since it is illegal to `const_cast` from `const DerivedContainer *` to `BaseContainer *`, I am not sure if this works in the case of polymorphism.

I would assume that the cast is still valid because the type of `this` would always be `const BaseContainer *` in `BaseContainer::operator[] const` because it is not virtual, but I am not sure if that's the correct way of doing this. Maybe it is simply better to define `operator[]` twice in this case?

Comment: `// Is this correct?` - no. Try this: `const DerivedContainer dc; Foo& f = dc[42];`. See a problem? Further: unless you can guarantee the *originating* object on whose reference ` const_cast` is stripping const-ness from is, in fact, non-const at inception, you're playing with fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would assume that the `const_cas`t is still valid because the type of this would always be `const BaseContainer *` in `BaseContainer::operator[] const` because it is not `virtual`, but I am not sure if that's the correct way of doing this.

Your understanding is correct. The code should work as intended.

There is another thing you have to think about, though. When you declare

```
Foo& operator[](int i);
```

in the derived class, the `const` version is not going to be found if the function call is made on a derived class object/reference/pointer. To be able to use it with a derived class object/reference/pointer, add the following in the derived class.

```
using BaseContainer::operator[];
```

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but `this` in `const Foo& operator[](int i) const` may still be a `DerivedContainer*` due to polymorphism?

Comment: @StephanLechner, sure it can. That should not be a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

The overloaded non-const-version in `DerivedContainer` will be called from the body of `BaseContainer::const operator[]` due to polymorphism. So from this point it is actually a "legal" design, although your assumption "this would always be const BaseContainer * in BaseContainer::operator[] const because it is not virtual" is - in the context of polymorphism - wrong.

See the following code illustrating the call chain:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void print() { cout << "Base.non-const;"; }
    void print() const { cout << "entry:Base.const;then..."; const_cast<Base *>(this)->print(); }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    void print() override { cout << "Derived.non-const;"; }
};

int main() {

    const Base* bc = new Derived;
    bc->print();
    //Output: entry:Base.const;then...Derived.non-const;

    cout << endl;

    Base* bnc = new Derived;
    bnc->print();
    // Output: Derived.non-const;
}
```

Note that the non-const-body of `operator[]` must not alter the `*this`-object if this object has originally been defined as `const`. Otherwise you get undefined behaviour.